# Does $\operatorname E[f(X_t)]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}f(x)$ and $Y_t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}y_0$ imply $\operatorname E[Y_tf(X_t)]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}f(x)y_0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probabiltiy space, $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $\operatorname P[X_0=x]=1$ and $f:E\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\operatorname E[f(X_t)]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}f(x)\tag1.$$

> Let $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a real-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $Y_t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}y_0\in\mathbb R$ almost surely. Are we able to infer that $$\operatorname E[Y_tf(X_t)]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}f(x)y_0?\tag2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Let $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then your question is whether $Y_t \rightarrow y_0$ a.s. implies $\mathbb{E}[Y_t] \rightarrow y_0$, which is definitely false.  More generally, if $X$ is any continuous process and $f$ any continuous function $f$ bounded away from $0$, then we can let $Z$ be any process with $Z_t \rightarrow z_0$ a.s. but $\mathbb{E}[Z_t] \not \rightarrow 0$ and set $Y_t = \frac{Z_t}{f(X_t)}$ for another counterexample.